# dependabot not working for file name other than libs.version.toml

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, toml

dependabot not working for file name other than libs.version.toml

i am using version catalog in my android app and i have multiple toml files to manage dependencies but when i enabled dependabot it is not working for file name other than libs.version.toml

```
[versions]
agp = "8.2.0-alpha11"
kotlin = "1.7.20"
core-ktx = "1.9.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
androidx-test-ext-junit = "1.1.5"
espresso-core = "3.5.1"
appcompat = "1.5.1"
material = "1.9.0"

[libraries]
core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "core-ktx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-test-ext-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "androidx-test-ext-junit" }
espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espresso-core" }
appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }

[bundles]
```

It should work for all toml files

Comment: Im having the same issue ... did you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: Not yet @jobernas